# Leaflet map missing on emailed html output

Tags: email, r, markdown

I have an RMarkdown html document with an interactive leaflet map.  When I email it to show someone, the leaflet map is missing.

I haven't been able to find any help online.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found that if I set self-contained to yes that it works.

date: "Report Date: `r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
    self_contained: yes